# Hotcakes Commerce Add to Cart button in DrillDown view

Tags: e-commerce

If we wanted an Add to Cart button in the DrillDown view and we wanted to use something like the following:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteHccUrl(HccRoute.Cart, new { quickaddsku = Products...Item.Sku })" class="add-to-cart" ></a>
```

What is the best method to find the current product item within the context of that view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drilldown category view could potentially return and iterate through thousands of products due to it's SPA nature. As you no doubt know, that view works using `KnockoutJS`, and as such, the data and client-side view are maintained much differently than most views. So, the amount of information returned for each product is limited.

You won't see "Add to Cart" buttons/links on the default views in general though, due to one thing... More overhead would need to be added to determine if the link could safely be "Add to Cart" or whether it should be "View Product" when a product has choices. So, you won't find an Add to Cart link in the view model, but you can create the add to cart link using the documentation below.

https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205426245-Add-Products-to-Cart-and-More-Using-Links

So, a direct add to cart link may look like this:  `/Cart?QuickAddSku=SAMPLE004&QuickAddQty=1`

In your case, editing this might look something like the example below:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '/Cart?QuickAddSku=' + ProductSku + '&QuickAddQty=1' }, text: ProductName"></a>
```

More information about these view models can be found in the links below.

https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212095386-DrillDownJsonModel

https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212097186-SingleProductJsonModel

Please let us know if this was helpful or not.